# How to use a jquery function in multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have a `Jquery function` and I want to run it on multiple pages also, can someone tell me hows it possible.

Here is code I am using

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
    setTimeout(function(){$(".logo").fadeIn(500);}, 500);


setTimeout(function(){
     $('#preloader').fadeIn(500)
    }, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){
$(window).load(function() { 

   $('#preloader').delay(200).fadeOut('fast'); 

  $(".logo").delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".content").fadeIn(500);
   });
}, 2000);//time out function close
});
```

I have another problem with same code, as you can see the code is making fadein and fadeout to *logo* and *preloader* and then contains is displaying, but this is working only one time. If i load page again by clicking refresh button of browser, the function will not work.

How can I solve those problems.

Comment: Put that is a js file, reference the file in all the pages you want to use

Comment: There is any trick to make it store in one code then it the code can use in all pages.?

Comment: no trick is needed, open a notepad file paste the jquery code, save the file with .js extension, use it in all the pages
In the head section of html give reference to the js file

Comment: create a fiddle for second part?

Comment: [There is link for the site i am working on](http://www.gate7infotech.com/projects/development/MyLuckyBottle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the functions that you want to reuse in a separate file. (Maybe you can call it CommonFunctions.js.) From there, you can call those functions as long as the file is included in the page.

Comment: I have done those things and i got it but still having problem 2nd thing i have mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the function a global variable

```
sayHello=function() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

Or

Create a common.js file and include that function. You can use this js to anywhere in project.